# Align Image with Text baseline in a Row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

How can I align an Image with a Text's baseline in a Row. `Modifier.alignByBaseline()` works for the Texts but the Image doesn't participate in the alignment.

```
@Composable
fun Sample() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "One",
            modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline(),
            fontSize = 40.sp
        )
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                .size(24.dp)
                .alignBy(FirstBaseline),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
            contentDescription = "",
        )
        Text(
            text = "two",
            modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline(),
            fontSize = 40.sp
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`alignByBaseline` aligns item by it's own baseline, not neighbours ones.

You can use `paddingFromBaseline` for `Text` and same value for image `padding` with `verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom`.

And to get actual value of baseline offset to pass it to the padding modifier, you need to wait for `TextLayoutResult`: it gets called when text layout is calculated depending on text size, font, etc.

```
Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    var maxBaseline by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    fun updateMaxBaseline(textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult) {
        maxBaseline = max(maxBaseline, textLayoutResult.size.height - textLayoutResult.lastBaseline)
    }
    val topBaselinePadding = with(LocalDensity.current) { maxBaseline.toDp() }
    Text(
        text = "One",
        modifier = Modifier.paddingFromBaseline(bottom = topBaselinePadding),
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        onTextLayout = ::updateMaxBaseline
    )
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(bottom = topBaselinePadding)
            .size(24.dp)
    )
    Text(
        text = "two",
        modifier = Modifier.paddingFromBaseline(bottom = topBaselinePadding),
        fontSize = 40.sp,
        onTextLayout = ::updateMaxBaseline
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where does the 15.dp come from?

Comment: @miguel ok actually that was a constant :D Only now the solution came to my mind how you can get real baseline value to pass it to these modifiers, check out updated answer